# Do we need to extend struts-default package always?

Tags: java, inheritance, struts2, struts-config, xml-configuration

Do we always need to extend the `struts-default` package? I am seeing following exception on server startup:

```
Caused by: Error building results for action loginScreen in namespace /User - action - file:/C:/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/Struts2Example/WEB-INF/classes/login.xml:9:30
```

**package:**

```
<package name="login" namespace="/User" >
    <action name="loginScreen">
        <result>pages/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

if I add the `extends="struts-default"` to above package then server is starts up without any error.

Can someone please give more details on this error/exception?

Comment: Read struts 2 in action.That would help you a lot.

Comment: Please read some books and go through some examples. If you get stuck in some concept, the community will help, but asking them to train ain't such a good idea. Always state what you've already tried in your question. I meant train because the question is too broad to be explained in here when you can easily find it with a quick-google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your configuration you are using a `dispatcher` result type by default to configure your result. But this type is defined in the `struts-default` package which your package should extend. It's not obligatory to extend this package, but to have support from the Struts2 framework you need at least your root package extend the `struts-default`.